# How to access items in an api return string in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I'm accessing the Google places API using HTTParty.  Here's my code.

```
 query = GOOGLE_API["search"].merge(:location => latlng.join(","))
      response = HTTParty.get(GOOGLE_API["search"]["url"], :query => query)
      @businessInfo = response
```

@business info contains a string of data from Google as expected, however, when I try to acccess the items using @businessInfo.index(0).item like I would with data from my database, I get nil.

```
This is a sample of what is contained in the variable --  {"html_attributions"=>[], "results"=>[{"geometry"=>{"location"=>{"lat"=>33.762835, "lng"=>-84.392724}}, "icon"=>"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/art_gallery-71.png", "id"=>"c551a5fdc78c273e6f498aa920733037199ebe01", "name"=>"World of Coca-Cola", "reference"=>"CnRoAAAAvpKSnn971Ur5ABYStk-EJfMvyFFFlBtd9LzwRT4H-PF50vS0CQtDCGkoW0QqKLHwFHV7Qmj32bgg-KjthkVENsBpGPxNAq_vcg4do-TQyi97y6mKxf3qUgoGxzGHePEAcqg15aATTl6Xdsq7Pl2b6hIQpzVIr4KO4ZDSx4tIqcH-ARoUPn-9yBSLi35lBM7gFm2KTPGREa0", "types"=>["art_gallery", "store", "establishment"], "vicinity"=>"Baker Street Northwest, Atlanta"}, {"geometry"=>{"location"=>{"lat"=>33.759925, "lng"=>-84.387158}}, "icon"=>"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png", "id"=>"32815dbf0963cb55dee871b96cc5100335f40400", "name"=>"Hard Rock Cafe Atlanta", "reference"=>"CnRtAAAApKIX3M3emqAzdsN3f0ntsi-M-
```

My question is,  What syntax do I use to access the items and values so that I can work with them.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok.. Figured it out. The iterator goes between the parent and the child hash. That wasn't clear at first.                            '  <% for i in 0..5 %>
 
 <ul>
  <li><%= @features['results'][i]['name'] %></li>
  
  </ul>

  <% end %>'

Answer (score 0):

Your response object is an [hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html) so you can access your response content in the following way:

```
puts response["results"]
```

Comment: Thanks! The remaining issue i have is that the values are nested. So there is no value returned from "Results".  I need something like Results.name or ["results"]["name], but unfortunately neither of these ways seems to work.  Is there a way to access the nested values under "Results"?